# Geo Location Fetch taken a more time in chrome 65.0.3325.181 With MAC

Tags: jquery, macos, google-chrome, geolocation

After allow Geo location in browser navigation 1 min taken a response.
This issue affected with this resources only please help to fix.

Google Chrome version : 65.0.3325.181 With MAC

[Link for Test](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error)

Comment: I am also dealing with the same issue. In my case, it's working fine when first time landing on the page. but after refreshing the page it's taking time as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this one exact issue.

Comment: I would suggest ask this question on chrome forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sxlXZ2IfQYs;context-place=mydiscussions